# Regular Expression in Word VBA Is Not Returning Correct Value

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have regular expression that I tested online to make sure it was correct. When I use it in MS Word, it is returning more than just the value I want it too.

Here is the Regular Expression `([nN][0-9].*-[tT].\S*[0-9])`

Here is the code I'm using in Word VBA:

```
 Dim regEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
 Set regEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
 Dim Matches As Object
        
 With regEx
   .IgnoreCase = False
   .MultiLine = True
   .Global = True    ' Only look for 1 match; False is actually the default.
   .pattern = "([nN][0-9].*-[tT].\S*[0-9])"  ' Word separates lines with CR (\r)
 End With
 Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
```

Here is an example of the text in my word document:

> Call me Ishmael. Some years ago - never mind how long precisely -
> having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to
> interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see
> the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the
> spleen, and regulating circulation. Whenever I find myself growing
> grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my
> soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin
> warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and
> especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it
> requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately
> stepping into the street, and methodologically knocking people's hats
> off - then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can.
> N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1
>  This is my substitute for pistol and ball...
> I quietly take to the ship. There is nothing surprising in this. If
> they but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time or other,
> cherish very nearly the same feelings towards the ocean with me:
>
> 1. Fish
> 2. Whales
> 3. Sharks
> 4. Ships

I want to get the `N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1` from the text, but instead it is returning the following:

> N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1 This is my substitute for pistol and ball... I
> quietly take to the ship. There is nothing surprising in this. If they
> but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time or other,
> cherish very nearly the same feelings towards the ocean with me:
>
> 1. Fish
> 2. Whales
> 3. Sharks
> 4. Ships

It's returning from the first found instance to the end of the document instead of the end of the matched value.

My document may have many instances of this pattern: N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1 and I need to pull out each one.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is the code as changed that is still not working:

```
    Dim regEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set regEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.matchCollection
    Dim Match As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
    
    With regEx
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = False    ' Only look for 1 match; False is actually the default.
        .pattern = "([nN][0-9].*-[tT].\S*[0-9])"  ' Word separates lines with CR (\r)
    End With
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
    For Each Match In Matches
        MsgBox (Match.value)
    Next Match
```

Here is what is showing up in my msgbox:
[image]

I have created a simple word document with the following data and it gives me the same issue:

> Call me Ishmael. Some years ago - never mind how long precisely -
> having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to
> interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see
> the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the
> spleen, and regulating circulation. Whenever I find myself growing
> grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my
> soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin
> warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and
> especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it
> requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately
> stepping into the street, and methodologically knocking people's hats
> off - then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can.
> N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1
>  This is my substitute for pistol and ball...
> I quietly take to the ship. There is nothing surprising in this. If
> they but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time or other,
> cherish very nearly the same feelings towards the ocean with me:
>
> 1. Fish
> 2. Whales
> 3. Sharks
> 4. Ships
>    N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1
>    N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1
>    N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1
>    N1.2.3-T1-Test-4.5-S1

If I remove the last 4 items it works.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx.Execute returns a **MatchCollection**, not a **Match**. Try this:

```
Sub Test()

 Dim regEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
 Set regEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
 Dim Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
 Dim Match As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
        
 With regEx
   .IgnoreCase = False
   .MultiLine = True
   .Global = True    ' Only look for 1 match; False is actually the default.
   .Pattern = "([nN][0-9].*-[tT].\S*[0-9])"  ' Word separates lines with CR (\r)
 End With
 Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
 For Each Match In Matches
    Debug.Print Match.Value
 Next Match
 
End Sub
```

Comment: This did not work. I still have the same results.

Comment: As requested I added my code and what my message box shows.

Comment: Got the solution from MSDN: I needed to change the pattern to:  "([nN][0-9].*?-[tT].\S*[0-9])"

Comment: That's weird. The original code worked for me. I am glad you found your solution (non-greedy matching).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RegEx for this - it can all be done quite simply with a *wildcard* Find in Word:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[Nn][0-9].[0-9].[0-9]-[Tt]*[Ss][0-9]>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Select
    MsgBox .Text
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```